# SpringEL Exception with Thymeleaf only seen in Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am asking this question because i get this error when running on jetty but when i run on tomcat everything is perfect. The error says there is an error with a field and this field should be public , but there is nothing wrong with field.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "employee.email" (template: "employees" - line 76, col 33)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
```

Comment: That error is from SpringEL triggering an exception in thymeleaf.  The differences in Tomcat or Jetty have nothing to do with that error.  This problem is entirely within the webapp.

Comment: But why is ok in tomcat but not jetty ?

Comment: Accident?  Both SpringEL and Thymleaf, do not ship with Jetty or Tomcat.  The exception you have provided shows nothing more then a SpringEL issue.  The exception is being reported due an unhandled exception flowing out of your webapp.  Jetty got the request, parsed it, and sent it down into your webapp.  Your webapp failed, Jetty just reported it.

Comment: Right now (with the information you have provided) this points squarely at SpringEL and/or Thymeleaf issue in your webapp.

Comment: I found the issue @JoakimErdfelt it was with my tests, so tomcat did not run the test while jetty did , thats why i was getting the error with jetty